# Where can I find a global life expectancy table?

Tags: data-request, demographics, biology, global

I've found good information on specific countries and demographics, but I can't seem to find global numbers. I know that the world life expectancy is around 71.0, but I'm trying to get a percentile breakdown in the form of something like an actuarial life table.

I've checked out sources like the [WHO](http://www.who.int/gho/mortality_burden_disease/life_tables/en/) and the [Worldbank](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.LE00.IN), but it doesn't really give me the data I'm looking for. I want something that is in a format similar to the [SSA life table](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the following links:

- http://205.207.175.93/hdi/ReportFolders/ReportFolders.aspx?IF_ActivePath=P,21
- http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/mortality/lewk3.htm
- http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/life-expectancy.htm

The WHO and World Bank can provide the data in your desired format if you reach out to the contact associated with the dataset.